# Predicting road accidents

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a dataset of road accidents  containing: location (latitude and longitude), date, time, country.

I would like to create a model to predict the existence of accidents for a given location.

My question is which attributes i can create  to build this model?

Comment: There is a corpus of published material on this subject.  Have you read any of their work, including what attributes they found informative?

Comment: I found an example that includes accidents causes like weather and traffic but the problem that i'm using my app to collect data so there is no data for accident causes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying location characteristics from the Google maps api or a package like  a [geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) and then adding weather [characteristics](https://openweathermap.org/history-bulk) would be a good place to start.

Comment: time of day, day of week, holiday status, vehicle type, level of traffic and driver type should also be considered.  Weather is good, including lighting, wind, and precipitation might be good.

Comment: @J_Heads Thank you for your response i will add it but my dataset will produce the predicted class (accident existence) only with value "yes" how can i add the "no" to my dataset

Comment: @EngrStudent thank you for your ideas but i can't get this informations from my app , do you have idea how to get for example traffic level

Comment: @honeyyy those types of questions are not really on topic here, http://opendata.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate.